# How to handle long polling in a spring boot app, load balanced by nginx?

Tags: javascript, nginx, spring-boot, stomp, spring-websocket

Let me first describe the given situation.

I have an angular JavaScript frontend. I need to use websockets, therefor I use "sockjs" and "stomp-websocket".

```
var socket,
    client;
socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/stomp');
client = Stomp.over(socket);
client.connect({}, function () {
  client.subscribe('/dummy/message', function (message) {
    console.log('subscribed');
  }
});
```

My backend is a Spring Boot application:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/dummy");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry
            .addEndpoint("/stomp")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS()
            .setSessionCookieNeeded(false);
    }
}
```

This setup works without any problems. Even when I disable websockets in firefox, it still works without any problems (fallback works in this scenario).

My problems start when I start more instances of my backend and use nginx.

My nginx config is:

```
upstream ws_be {
    server localhost:8081;
    server localhost:8082;
}

server {
    listen 8080;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ws_be;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

When I use this setup with multiple backends, websockets still work as intended **but** if i disable websockets in my browser the fallback does not work anymore. It just keeps connecting and instant disconnecting.

Error in browser console:

```
Opening Web Socket...  stomp.min.js:8:1893
Web Socket Opened...  stomp.min.js:8:1893
>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

<<< CONNECTED
version:1.1
heart-beat:0,0

connected to server undefined  stomp.min.js:8:1893
>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/dummy/message

Whoops! Lost connection to undefined
```

On the backend I get an IO broken pipe error:

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)
```

At this point I have no idea how I have to configure the nginx or my backend to work properly with the given setup.
Now I hope someone has an idea or a hint for this problem.

Comment: could you check in your browser devtools which transport is chosen by the browser and what error message do you get in the network tab?

Comment: It keeps repeating this four requests:
- GET  http://localhost:8080/stomp/info -> Status 200
- POST http://localhost:8080/stomp/101/x_bobkwk/xhr_streaming -> Status 200 Aborted
- POST http://localhost:8080/stomp/101/x_bobkwk/xhr_send -> Status 204
- POST http://localhost:8080/stomp/101/x_bobkwk/xhr_send -> Status 404

Comment: In that case, maybe it's related to this? https://serverfault.com/questions/789417/should-proxy-buffering-be-disabled-in-nginx-to-support-sockjs-xhr-streaming

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried disabling the proxy_buffering, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: try without nginx - if it works, it means this question should be about nginx (and moved to serverfault)

Answer (score 1):

I found one solution, that may work for others. It works with sticky session (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#ip_hash)

```
upstream ws_be {
    ip_hash;
    server localhost:8081;
    server localhost:8082;
}
```

Unfortunately, I am not allowed to use sticky sessions. Therefor my search continuous.